# Change viewport scale at runtime?

Tags: javascript, html

I want to set the viewport scale at runtime - should mobile browsers immediately apply the change after setting?  This is what I'm trying:

```
var scale = 2.0;
var viewport = document.getElementById("viewport"); 
if (viewport != null) {
    viewport.setAttribute("content", 
        "initial-scale=" + scale + ", " +
        "maximum-scale=" + scale + ", " +
        "minimum-scale=" + scale + ", " +
        "user-scalable=no");
}
```

but it does not seem to work. Basically I want a button that doubles the viewport scale when pressed. I'm primarily targeting mobile safari.

Thanks

Comment: Don't use semi-colons (`;`), use commas (`,`) in your attribute string

Comment: @ahren ok thanks updated - gave it another try, but there doesn't seem to be any visual change when I run that code in response to a button click on my iphone (4s). Thanks

Comment: You may also need to set `minimum-scale` - as I think the `initial-scale` is only effective on page load...

Comment: Ok added minimum-scale, still no luck. The initial settings are respected, though (like if I set the above params just in the html head, and reload the page, the scale is respected).

Comment: not to sound condescending - but does your HTML element have the id `viewport` ?

Comment: Ah no I had a different issue - I'm using GWT (which compiles out to javascript), but we have to reference the document like "$doc" instead of how I have it above. Thank you for your help, can you put up a comment as an answer so I can accept it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A couple of things to consider:

- The viewport content string should be comma separated, rather than a series of statements.
- `minimum-scale` should probably be in there, as I believe `initial-scale` is only for page load.